# Indirect Speech Backshifting in Commands & Requests with Time Clauses

Tags: indirect-speech, backshifting

I know that backshifting can used when reporting *statements* and *questions*. This is clearly stated in many grammar books. Aside from a mere example on some webpage, I haven't found any reference in the authentic books and websites I've checked that I could use as a **proof** that backshifting can be used in reported **imperatives** and **requests** with *complex time clauses*.

If backshifting can be used what is the rule for using it in the imperative and request sentences? Always used? depends on whether the reported situation out-of-time or not? never used?

The following is some sample request and imperative sentences with reported speech as I see it for the first two sentences. Pronouns are not important. Choose as you see fit.

> Can I come back again when I find my book?
>   I asked her **to come** back when I **found** my book.
>
> Come back when you find your lost keys
>   He told me to come back when I found my lost keys
>
> Shutdown the computer before you leave
>
> Do exercise 10A after you've finished this one
>
> Tidy up now if you are leaving tonight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I come back again when I find my book? **I asked her if I could come back again when I had found my book.**

Come back when you find your lost keys.
**He told me to come back when I had found my lost keys.**

Shutdown the computer before you leave. **He told me to shut down the computer before I left.**

Do exercise 10A after you've finished this one.
**She told me to do exercise 10A after I’d finished that one.**

Tidy up now if you are leaving tonight.
**He told me to tidy up then if I was leaving that night.**

Comment: Surely backshifting refers to a change between equivalent sentences in quote structures and report structures. The first pair refer to different scenarios.

Comment: Quite right. I've changed the reported version.

Comment: Can't the first sentence be understood/treated as a request? as in "Can you pick me up at 5 pm?"

Comment: Yes, it can. Or perhaps as a suggestion.